# <li><a href="customer/account">My Account</a></li> error does not clear when next footer link clicked

Tags: error, footer, link

href="customer/account" My Account when on the page this link goes to then I click on another footer link I get for example ://mydomain.com/customer/account/login/about-us

Comment: Change `"customer/account" `  to `//mydomain.com/customer/account`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your link `href="about-us"`, when you click on the link, it will lead you to the `current url` with your `href` value. For example, if you are on the customer login page, it will lead you to an incorrect url: `mydomain.com/customer/account/login/` + `about-us`.

In your case (Magento site domain uses the main domain), your `href` value should start with a forward slash `/`, it is: `href="/about-us"`.

If you working in a `phtml` file, you should use the below code to build your url, it will work for all cases:

```
href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBaseUrl() . 'about-us' ?>"
```

Comment: amazing thank you, I am working with Porto theme my other theme by Welt does not have this problem it uses <li><a href="{{store url=about}}">About Us</a></li> for footer links. The link to customer account in Porto Theme out of the box is just "#" so I copied /customer/account/login from my other site

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please mark this answer as **accepted**, it makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer.